# Letsencrypt Error Account creation on ACMEv1 is disabled

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am trying to install LetsEncrypt SSL certificate on Amazon Linux AMI

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09
```

I am following the blog mentioned in https://medium.com/@mohan08p/install-and-renew-lets-encrypt-ssl-on-amazon-ami-6d3e0a61693

But in the final step of execution, I am getting an error

```
{
  "type": "urn:acme:error:unauthorized",
  "detail": "Account creation on ACMEv1 is disabled. Please upgrade your ACME client to a version that supports ACMEv2 / RFC 8555. See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430 for details.",
  "status": 403
}
```

Please help how should I proceed?